# AngularJS $http GET call getting stuck

Tags: angularjs, http

I have below function for calling HTTP REST APIs in my AngularJS APP.

```
function callHTTPApi(URL, method, postData, successCB, failureCB )
{

  $http({
    url: URL, 
    method: method, 
    cache: false,
    data: postData,
    headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
        }
    }).
    then(
        function(response) 
        {
            var data = response.data || "Request failed";
            successCB(data);
        }, 
        function(response) 
        {
            console.error("Error in HTTP response: "+JSON.stringify(response));
            var data = response.data || "Request failed";
            var status = response.status;
            failureCB(data, status);
        }
    );
}
```

Problem is that sometimes my application gets stuck when I call this method, and I don't receive success or failure call back.

I have this function in My Service and it has been used across controllers.

Is this the right way of calling HTTP GET request from Angular?

**UPDATE**

Whe I call this method for GET request, then application gets stuck and in the logs I see error:

```
Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue
```

Comment: did you inject the $http dependency in your service? are you getting anything in your console?

Comment: i think, cannot able to postdata in httpGet, only you can get data(json,xml) from server. so remove data option and try it. pls refer doc [httpget](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get)

Comment: "and I don't receive success or failure call back" I don't think so.. Can you do some debug ? :-)

Comment: @pandian_Snkl As this method is common for all the controllers, in case of GET request we send post data as null. And about the debugging I can not live debug this app as this is phonegap based application which runs on iPad. Some times when I call this method my app gets stuck and in the logs I see errors related to memory, please see my updated question.